# Matrix for a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Consider $V= \left \{ v= \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3
\end{bmatrix} : x_1-x_2+2x_3=0\right \}\subset K^3$ and the linear map $f:V \rightarrow K^2$ defined by

$f\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1-x_3\\ 
x_2-3x_3
\end{pmatrix}$

Now, what is the matrix $M$ that represents $f:V \rightarrow K^2$ with respect to the basis of $V$ and the standard basis $(e_1,e_2)$ for $K^2$.

**So far**

I found the basis of V of dimension 2 to be the vectors  ${(1, 1, 0), (-2, 0, 1)}$. But then I do not know how to continue. Maybe coordinate shift?

Comment: What does $f$ do to the vectors in the basis of $V$? i.e. which vectors do they map to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple errors/unclear parts in your question. I'm not very sure what the set $K$ is, so I will be assuming it's the field $\mathbb{R}$.

<s>Also, the codomain of $f$ seems to be $K^2$ rather than $K^3$, so I assume $f:V \to K^3$ was a typographic error on your part.</s>

Now, a "matrix representation of a linear transformation $g:A \to B$" only makes sense when we're given specific ordered bases of $A$ and $B$. You gave us $B_{K_2}=(e_1,e_2)$ for $K^2$ but ordered the basis of $V$ with respect to which we will find the matrix representation is not very clear. I will assume it is the ordered basis $B_{V}=((1,1,0),(-2,0,1))$.

I will assume that you are familiar with the theory behind matrix representations of a linear transformation and I will simply find the representation. If anything within this process is unclear, just let me know.

First, we will find the images of elements of $B_V$ under $f$, expressed as linear combinations of elements of $B_{K^2}$.

$$f(1,1,0)=(1-0,1-3 \cdot 0)=(1,1)=1 \cdot (1,0) + 1\cdot (0,1) = \textbf{1} \cdot e_1 + \textbf{1} \cdot e_2$$
$$f(-2,0,1)=(-2-1,0-3\cdot 1)=(-3,-3)=(-3) \cdot(1,0) + (-3) \cdot (0,1) = \textbf{(-3)} \cdot e_1 + \textbf{(-3)} \cdot e_2$$

Now, we will simply take the coefficients written in bold and place them in our representation matrix. Remember, the i-th column represents the coefficients of the linear combination of the i-th element of $B_V$ in terms of the elements of $B_{K^2}$.

$$[f]^{B_V}_{B_{K^2}}= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3 \\
1 & -3
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Yes  there was a mistake regarding $K^2$.

Comment: @mathstudent23 alright then, I'll edit those parts out.

Comment: but this is all the info I am given

Comment: Well, a "matrix representation of a linear transformation" is only defined with respect to specific ordered bases. Could it be the case that you are expected to find a matrix representation of $f$ with respect to *any* choice of ordered bases $B_V$ and $B_{K^2}$?

Comment: it is with respect to the found basis (the one i found in the post) and the standardbasis $(e_1,e_2)$ for $K^2$.

Comment: Everything seems to be correct then, no? Perhaps the choice of the field $K$ is not very clear, but since we have expressions such as $2\cdot x_3$ and $3 \cdot x_3$, we may deduce that $K$ is a field with  $2,3 \in K$ . This led me to guess that $K=\mathbb{R}$. Keep in mind that this type of "guessing" is not a mathematical statement or process of some sort, I'm just trying to fill in the gaps with what we have.

Comment: We use $K$ as complex or real numbers in generel in my course.

Comment: The matrix should be correct either way.

Comment: 1 quick question I think I get it all now but; Does it matter which vector i use in which column in the final matrix? I.e could I swap the (1,1) column with (-3,-3)?

Comment: The order in which you write the columns does actually matter. $B_V$ and $B_{K^2}$ are ordered bases, and the $ij$-entry of $[f]^{B_V}_{B_{K^2}}$ must be the coefficient of the $j$-th vector of $B_{K^2}$ in the linear combination we obtain when expressing the $i$-th vector in $B_V$ in terms of the elements of $B_{K^2}$. In other words, the $i$-th row stands for the $i$-th vector in $B_{K^2}$ and the $j$-th column stands for the $j$-th vector in $B_V$, so the order does actually matter.

Comment: Yes I was thinking that it would matter, but how did you know which column to use first? Sorry for the barrage but this is really new to me.

Comment: Absolutely no need to be sorry. You had already given us the order of elements in $B_{K^2}=(e_1,e_2)$. I simply chose $B_V=((1,1,0),(-2,0,1))$ to be in the same order you wrote its vectors in. Of course, I could have used $B_V'=((-2,0,1),(1,1,0))$ and the matrix representation would be equally valid, but that would be a matrix representation of $f$ with respect to *different* ordered bases. So yes, "swapping" the columns would get you a valid but *different* representation of $f$.

Comment: Okay got it. I wrote it in the correct order to be safe so it should indeed be correct. Thanks for the explanation(s)

Comment: No problem, best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, will need it. Have to show it isn't a isomorphism now.

Comment: Well that's not very difficult. Just find two elements of $V$ that have the same image under $f$ (So $f$ isn't injective, and thus not bijective, and consequently not an isomorphism) or show that $Im(f)\neq K^2$.

Comment: Hey @Y. Tamer   - another user got a similar problem to mine; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959711/matrix-for-a-linear-map-between-2-different-basis/3959759#3959759 - how would one go about this kind of question. I think - and OP - that the comment was a bit too advanced.

Answer (score 0):

In the general (finite dimensional) case, given a linear transformation between two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ as well as basis $\mathcal{B}_{V} = \{v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,n\}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{W} = \{w_{1},w_{2},\ldots,w_{m}\}$ where $n = \dim V$ and $m = \dim W$, the matricial representation of $T:V\to W$ is given by
\begin{align*}
[T]_{\mathcal{B}_{V}}^{\mathcal{B}_{W}} = [[T(v_{1})]_{\mathcal{B}_{W}} [T(v_{2})]_{\mathcal{B}_{W}} \ldots [T(v_{n})]_{\mathcal{B}_{W}}]
\end{align*}

At your case, we are given $V$ (which is a plane) and $W$ (which coincides with $\mathbb{K}^{2}$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is the field of scalars, I assume).

Given that $B_{V} = \{(1,1,0),(-2,0,1)\}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{W} = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
f(1,1,0) = (1,1) = (1,0) + (0,1)\\\\
f(-2,0,1) = (-3,-3) = -3(1,0) -3(0,1)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Consequently, one can conclude that
\begin{align*}
[f]_{\mathcal{B}_{V}}^{\mathcal{B}_{W}} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3\\
1 & -3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: 1 quick question I think I get it all now but; Does it matter which vector i use in which column in the final matrix? I.e could I swap the (1,1) column with (-3,-3)?

Comment: No, you cannot. In fact, when we choose a basis, the order of the vectors is important.

Comment: Okay; so; the order of my basis is the order of columns in the matrix $A$?

Comment: Yes. Precisely speaking, given two basis $\mathcal{B}_{V}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{W}$ as previously mentioned, one has that
\begin{align*}
[T]_{\mathcal{B}_{V}}^{\mathcal{B}_{W}} = [[T(v_{1})]_{\mathcal{B}_{W}} [T(v_{2})]_{\mathcal{B}_{W}} \ldots [T(v_{n})]_{\mathcal{B}_{W}}]
\end{align*}