# Matrix for a linear map between 2 different basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let a map with the field $K$, from $f:K^3 \rightarrow K^2$ be defined as $f\left (\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3
\end{bmatrix}  \right )=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1+2x_2+3x_3\\ 
3x_1+2x_2+x_3
\end{pmatrix}$

and the basis $\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
0\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
3\\ 
1\\ 
-1
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
-1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$ for $K^3$ and the basis $\begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
3
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix}$ for $K^2$

**Question**

Find the matrix that represents $f:K^3 \rightarrow K^2$ with respect to the given standardbasis for the domain and the codomain.

**My effort so far**

I am thinking that I first have to evaluate the vectors in the basis for $K^3$ and thus get some scalar. I then multiply the scalar on the basis for $K^2$. I.e If I evaluate $\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
0\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix}$ I get $(5,-1)$. I would then have to multiply that onto both my basis vectors i.e $5(2,3)+-1(1,2)=(10,15)+(-1,-2)=(9,13)$. That would give my first column in the matrix for the representation and thus I would end up with a matrix with 2 rows and 3 columns. This sounds wrong to me and I just want to have a quick check.

Comment: edited to fix a small mistake in the calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** You should not multiply your basis vectors with $(5,−1)$, but rather express $(5,-1)$ in terms of your basis vectors.

**SOLUTION:**

> $f(-1,0,2)=(5,-1)=\textbf{11} \cdot (2,3) + \textbf{(-17)} \cdot (1,2)$
>  $f(3,1,-1)=(2,10)=\textbf{(-6)} \cdot  (2,3) + \textbf{14} \cdot (1,2)$
>  $f(1,-1,1)=(2,2)=\textbf{2} \cdot (2,3) + \textbf{(-2)} \cdot (1,2)$
>  Let $B_1=((-1,0,2),(3,1,-1),(1,-1,1)), B_2=((2,3),(1,2))$.
>  Then, $[f]^{B_1}_{B_2}=\begin{bmatrix} 11 & -6 & 2\\ -17 & 14 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$

**EDIT:**
How does one express $(5,-1)$ in terms of $(2,3)$ and $(1,2)$?

Since $\text{span}(\{(2,3),(1,2)\})=K^2$ and $(5,-1)\in K^2$, we know there exist $a,b \in K$ such that $$(5,-1) = a \cdot (2,3) + b \cdot (1,2)$$
Applying the scalar multiplication, we have the following: $$(5,-1)=(a \cdot 2, a \cdot 3) + (b \cdot 1, b \cdot 2)$$
Adding the two 2-tuples together, we have $$(5,-1)=(a \cdot 2 + b \cdot 1, a \cdot 3 + b \cdot 2)$$
This implies:
$$2\cdot a+b=5$$
$$3\cdot a + 2 \cdot b = -1$$

I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: I am not sure how you aquire thoes numbers i.e 11 and -17 in the first one. Is that just a wavehand solution from looking at it?

Comment: Ah, perhaps that was not very clear. Let me edit my post.

Comment: Okay I see that just seems like an awful lot of calculations just for a simple introductory question out of 7.

Comment: I'd agree that it's tedious, but conceptually this is as simple as it gets. Hope I could make everything clear.

Comment: yes it did. So just solve 3 systems of equations; 1 for each of the basis vectors and I am done.

Comment: Exactly. I wish you good luck.

Comment: Hello @Y. Tamer - I am almost done but looking at this last one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960095/identity-map-with-change-of-basis/3960099#3960099 Mind helping?

Comment: I will take a look when I have the time.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider our bases.
For $K^3$, we have the base $\mathcal A = \{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$, where $a_1 = (-1,0,2)$, $a_2 = (3,1,-1)$ and $a_3 = (1,-1,1)$.
For $K^2$, we have the base $\mathcal B = \{b_1,b_2\}$, where $b_1 = (2,3)$ and $b_2 = (1,2)$.

The matrix $M$ that represents $f$ must satisfy the following property:

$$M[v]_{\mathcal A} = [f(v)]_{\mathcal B},$$

where $[u]_{\mathcal C}$ denotes $u$ written in base $\mathcal C$.
For this kind of exercise, I think it's good to consider the following:

1. A linear transformation $K^n\mapsto K^m$ is represented by an $m\times n$ matrix;
2. If $M$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $e_i$ is the  $n\times 1$ vector with all entries equal to $0$ except that the $i$-th entry is $1$, then $Me_i$ is the $i$-th column of $M$;
3. If $\mathcal C = \{c_1,\dots, c_n\}$ is an ordered basis of some vector space, then $[c_i]_{\mathcal C} = e_i$.

From $(1)$, we know that $M$ will be $2\times 3$ (so you are correct in this regard, that's 2 rows and 3 columns).
Of course, to find out $M$, all we need to do is find $M$'s columns.
$(3)$ implies that

$$M[a_i]_{\mathcal A} = Me_i = [f(a_i)]_{\mathcal B},$$

or in other words, the $i$-th column of $M$ is given by $f(a_i)$ written in base $\mathcal B$.

Do you think you can finish?
You answer is incorrect in this last regard.

Comment: I found the matrix that represents the map to be $A=\begin{pmatrix}
9 &14  &6 \\ 
 13&26  &10 
\end{pmatrix}$ but that was with "my method". I am not sure on what to actually take from this since it is written rather complex for my current expertise in Linera algebra, unfortunately.

Comment: Is this incorrect?

Comment: Your answer is not correct. We can try and break that in parts. What is the first part you are having trouble understanding from my answer? Do you understand how to write a vector in some given basis?