# Identity map with change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let a map with the field $K$, from $f:K^3 \rightarrow K^2$ be defined as $f\left (\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3
\end{bmatrix}  \right )=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1+2x_2+3x_3\\ 
3x_1+2x_2+x_3
\end{pmatrix}$

and the basis $\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
0\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
3\\ 
1\\ 
-1
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
-1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$ for $K^3$ and the standard basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ for the codomain

**Question**

Find the matrix that represents $Id:K^3 \rightarrow K^3$ with respect to the given basis for the domain and the standard basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ codomain.

I have found the matrix that represents $f:K^3 \rightarrow K^2$ with respect to the given standardbasis for the domain and the codomain but this identity map is really difficult for me to get.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Given any linear transformation, the columns of the matrix that represents that map are exactly the images of the basis vectors of the domain, expressed in the basis of the codomain.

Comment: so evaluate the basis vectors of the domain then multiplying them each with the standard basis of the co domain? edit: No I am still lost, forgot it is just the identity map.

Comment: No multiplication. Just take the three basis vectors, push them through the identity map (which doesn't change them at all), then express them using the standard basis (which you have already done). Those are the columns of your identity map matrix.

Comment: Oh i see so it is just the 3 vectors in their corresponding column from first to third and that is the whole matrix.

Comment: Yup. That's all there is to it. Of course, usually, there is at least a little calculation involved in finding the columns of a matrix that represents a given linear transformation. But not this time.

Comment: But as a generel result; if the codomain is the standard basis $(e_1,e_2,...,e_n)$ would the matrix representing the map just be the basis vectors corresponding to their column i.e $1,..,j$? I got a similar question but regarding a basis with 2 vectors into the codomain with basis  $(e_1,e_2)$ for the identity map, again.

Comment: The general result is what I've stated in my actual answer post. Take the basis vectors of the domain, apply the linear transformation you're interested in to those vectors, then express the result in the basis of the codomain. The result is the columns of the matrix that represents the linear transformation. In particular, if you have the vectors of basis A expressed using basis B, then those are the columns of the matrix that translates from basis A to basis B.

Answer (score 1):

A general recipe for this:

Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field $k$, and write $n = \dim V$ and $m = \dim W$. Also, consider ordered basis $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ for $V$ and $(w_1,\dots,w_m)$ for $W$. Now, if $T : V \to W$ is a linear map, the matrix that represents $T$ with respect to $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ and $(w_1,\dots,w_m)$ is the $m \times n$ matrix with entries in $k$ obtained as follows

- First compute the $n$ vectors $Tv_1,\dots,Tv_n$.
- For each $j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ write $Tv_j$ as a linear combination of $w_1,\dots,w_m$, that is, find $a_{1j},\dots,a_{mj} \in k$ such that $Tv_j = a_{1j}w_1+\cdots+a_{mj}w_m$.
- Now, for each $j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ we have that the $j$-th column of the desired matrix is given by $$\begin{pmatrix} a_{1j} \\ \vdots \\ a_{mj} \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Oh i see so it is just the 3 vectors in my basis in their corresponding column from first to third and that is the whole matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the question as you asked it doesn't make any sense. I'm pretty sure you mixed together two unrelated questions. I suggest you check the source (the textbook or the instructor's original assignment), and I bet these are two separate parts being two separate questions, not a single question.

For starters, if the given function is $f:K^3\to K^2$, then we can't have *"the standard basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ for the codomain"*, because the dimension of the codomain is $2$, not $3$.

My guess is that there's a separate question about finding the matrix representing the given transformation $f$ with respect to some bases in the domain $K^3$ and in the codomain $K^2$, and there's a separate question about finding the matrix representing the identity map $\operatorname{Id}:K^3\to K^3$ with respect to the given basis in the domain $K^3$ and the standard basis in the codomain $K^3$ — but the map $f$ has nothing to do with this question.

To address this latter question, the answer is already in the question. :-) Technically speaking, you need to do what other responses have already said. To find the matrix of a linear transformation $T$, such as e.g. $T=\operatorname{Id}$, you do the following: for each given basis vector $\mathbf{b}_i$ (of the "domain" basis), calculate $T(\mathbf{b}_i)=\operatorname{Id}(\mathbf{b}_i)$, and the components of the resulting vectors with respect to the codomain basis will be the corresponding columns of the desired matrix. And since in the codomain we're using the standard basis, what are we going to see as these columns?